# "failed to create symbolic link" error when updating initramfs

Tags: initramfs

I have 15.04 installed and I get this error (not blocking, everything works but seeing this is annoying) while updating:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-16-generic
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/root/lib/systemd/system/cdrom.mount’: No such file or directory
```

I digged some and found out that I get this when I try to update initramfs:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Searched online but couldn't find anything related. I don't have a cdrom/dvdrom on my machine by the way.

Comment: Are you booting from a USB thumb drive?

Comment: No but I installed from USB thumb drive and my PC doesn't have a CD/DVD rom.

Comment: Well, in my case, I boot and use Ubuntu off a USB drive, and whenever I do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and if it updates packages like linux kernels, I would see errors as such. That is even with the computer having a CDRom Drive

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that there is a bug in whatever package `update-initramfs` is running the update for, where it is trying to generate the `cdrom.mount` symbolic link at the wrong path, `/root/lib/systemd/system/`, rather than at `/lib/systemd/system/`.

Which package is causing this? We need more information.

I have discovered that if you manually create that empty folder structure under `/root` before running anything, it will *then* create a cdrom.mount symbolic link there during the update. I would assume that one might even think to manually copy that symbolic link over to `/lib/systemd/system/`. I tried that, but I don't know if doing it actually fixes any problems.